# Criar arquivo .bat para abrir terminal Node.js e executar um ou mais comandos

Tags: node.js, batch

Gostaria de criar um arquivo .bat para automatizar um processo que tenho que realizar todo dia.

Sempre que vou começar a trabalhar, abro o terminal do nodejs, acesso o diretório do meu projeto (no meu caso utilizo o babel) e depois, preciso executar o comando `npm run babel`.

O problema é que trabalho em mais de um projeto. Aí às vezes tenho que ficar navegando pelo terminal até o diretório e depois, preciso executar o comando para iniciar o babel.

Eu gostaria de criar um arquivo .bat para cada projeto, para já deixar tudo configurado e quando eu clicar no arquivo .bat do projeto que eu quero, ele abra o terminal do nodejs e execute os comandos que eu desejo. Isso é possível?

Comment: É possível sim, basta criar o arquivo bat com os comandos que deseja que sejam executados. Você tem dificuldade na criação do arquivo? É só ir colocando os comandos que você quer que execute, 1 por linha, na ordem. PS se você acredita estar perdendo tempo digitando um caminho longo no `cd`, talvez seja melhor criar atalhos para as pastas no home dir.

Comment: Sim. Eu não tenho experiência na criação desse tipo de arquivo. Tentei alguns exemplos que encontrei na internet, mas não tive sucesso. O que eu queria saber é qual é o comando que eu devo usar para abrir o terminal do nodejs e como eu devo colocar os comandos de npm dentro desse arquivo.bat?

Comment: Na verdade, acho que não existe algo chamado "terminal do nodejs", e dentro o .bat vc coloca os comandos exatamente iguais vc digita no cmd, não muda nada. Não sei se entendi errado mas adicionei uma resposta, veja se é isso que precisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta criar um arquivo `iniciar_projeto.bat` com algo como:

```
cd C:\Users\Alan\Documentos\Seu_Projeto\
npm run babel
```

O primeiro comando deve ser, obviamente, alterado para o caminho do seu projeto. Isso é suficiente para rodar o servidor, se tudo estiver configurado corretamente.

Se o .bat estiver no D: e o seu projeto estiver no drive C:, é necessário mudar de volume primeiro:

```
c:
cd C:\Users\Alan\Documentos\Seu_Projeto\
npm run babel
```

Comment: Valeu cara. Eu havia tentando exatamente isso também. Mas não tinha funcionado antes. Porem, agora que você postou, insisti no teste e descobri porque deu errado na primeira vez. Eu havia criado o arquivo.bat no diretorio D: e meu projeto teste estava no C: ai sempre que executava o arquivo.bat não rolava. Mas depois da sua resposta testei salvando o arquivo.bat no C: e deu certo. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Ah sim, para mudar de diretório no Windows tem que digitar a letra sem o `cd`, editei a resposta pra exemplificar. Estranho né? cmd é tão zoado que a Microsoft preferiu implementar o bash do linux ao invés de consertá-lo.

Comment: Sim. Também estranhei isso. pq ja havia me acostumado com cd para acessar diretórios. Mas tudo bem. De qualquer forma, valeu pela ajuda!